# Telegram, what is Geolocation method used?

Tags: python, geolocation, telegram-bot

I am developing a Telegram bot. During the conversation bot asks the location_request in this way:

```
reply_keyboard = [[KeyboardButton("Send Location", request_location=True)],
                  [KeyboardButton("/cancel")]
                 ]
update.message.reply_text('Share your location:',
            reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard))
```

How to know the geolocation method used by device?

For instance:

- GPS in the device
- triangolation among the cells
- manual positioning

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't know about it :(

Even Telegram itself, it didn't verify this data from phone, so there might have someone use *Fake GPS*.